# The album artwork is not appearing on my iPhone (6GB, 4G) but it appears on my computer

Tags: iphone, album-art

The album artwork is not appearing on my iPhone (6GB, 4G) but it appears on my computer. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm having similar issues.  Do you find that artwork from music bought from iTunes shows up, but music from ripped CD or other sources doesn't?

Comment: Are you using iTunes in the cloud?  I found that my 4G would take a few moments to render artwork in coverflow for local music, but for cloud-stored music it doesn't render album art at all (in any view, not just coverflow) until the album is played.